# Not able to compile C program which is including <linux/leds.h>

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, kernel

I am trying to compile my led wrapper function program file with including **linux/leds.h**

using including kernel space header files
**gcc -I /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic/include/ example.c**

by compiling it flooded the console with errors in many headers file those are depended on leds.h. Can any one please help me to compile this C file which is using kernel space header files in user space.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

This won't work.

First of all, *don't* use kernel-mode headers in user-mode programs, except for the (processed?) ones provided for userspace after kernel compilation. Kernel-mode headers depend on the kernel build system to work.

I tried this, just for curiosity, although I did already knew why it won't work (tl;dr, I use the Ubuntu-patched 3.13.0-24 kernel):

```
$ cd /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/
$ echo '#include <linux/leds.h>' | gcc -E -x c -o - - -Iinclude
```

The preprocessor claims that `<asm/linkage.h>` is missing, and, correct me if I'm wrong, that header is generated by the kernel build system.

If you want, you can solve this by creating a kernel module that uses `<linux/leds.h>` *et al*, then export a userspace API through the module (usually done through `/proc` or `/sys`) and use that API to implement your usermode code's logic.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KemyLand, You were right that we can not use kernel space header file in user space. But your approach couldn't work for me. firstly it asked for asm/linkage.h, i included the path of it explicitly but again compilation terminated on another header file and i did same. But at last i blocked on some errors in headers files, which were not expected as i didn't make any changes in those files.                                                                                                                 but finally i got the solution. basically we have to do Interfacing functions between kernel space and the hardware device. I had to generate make file for it.                                                               **obj-m :=file_name.o**                                                                    and compiled it by following command **make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic/ -C /usr/include/ M=`pwd` modules** it generated 4 files file_name.mod.o , file_name.o, file_name.ko, file_name.mod.c.  and then loaded the module as root by **insmod file_name.ko**. for checking the loaded module type command **lsmod**. I can also execute it by typing command insmod ./file_name.o or can remove by **rmmod file_name**